# Select text inside editable field in CKEditor widget

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a CKEditor widget with some tables with editable fields.

I need to select all the text inside the field when a user clicks it, to make changing the text faster.

For now I was able to come up with this:

```
editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
widget = editor.widgets.instances[0]

$.each(widget.editables, function(e) {
    element = $(this.$);
    element.on( 'click', function( ev ) {
        elementId = editor.document.getActive().getId()
        editor.getSelection().selectElement( editor.document.getById(elementId) );
    });
});
```

Basically, I get all editable elements and bind a click event to them. My problem is only on how to select the text inside the editable element, since currently all I managed to do is select the element itself.

EDIT: I looked thoroughly in StackOverflow, and even though my question was marked as duplicated, none of the other answers describes my problem. The question marked as duplicated is telling how to get the currently selected text, when my problem is how to SELECT the text inside a node.

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=ckeditor+get+Selected+Text+2018

Comment: You should try to understand questions first before saying I had no effort before asking. I had already researched all of those results.

None of them really helped me. I need to select only the text inside a node, but I'm only able to select the node itself.